# Kafka consumer is taking time to recognize new partition

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I was running a test where kafka consumer was reading data from multiple partitions of a topic. While the process was running I added more partitions. It took around 5 minutes for consumer thread to read data from the new partition. I have found this configuration "topic.metadata.refresh.interval.ms", but this is for producer only. Is there a similar config for consumer too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed "metadata.max.age.ms" parameter value to refresh matadata https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#consumerconfigs_metadata.max.age.ms

Answer (score 2):

When we add more partitions to an existing topic then a rebalance process gets initiated.

Every consumer in a consumer group is assigned one or more topic partitions exclusively, and Rebalance is the re-assignment of partition ownership among consumers.

A Rebalance happens when:

1. consumer JOINS the group
2. consumer SHUTS DOWN cleanly
3. consumer is considered DEAD by the group coordinator. This may happen after a
   crash or when the consumer is busy with long-running processing, which means
   that no heartbeats have been sent in the meanwhile by the consumer to the
   group coordinator within the configured session interval
4. `new partitions are added`

We need to provide two parameters to reduce the time to rebalance.

```
request.timeout.ms

max.poll.interval.ms
```

More detailed information is available at the following.

https://medium.com/streamthoughts/apache-kafka-rebalance-protocol-or-the-magic-behind-your-streams-applications-e94baf68e4f2