# Consumer not reading from new partitions of a topic

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I increased the number of partitions for a topic from 10 to 20 and have one kafka connect(consumer) for that topic. After increasing the partitions the consumer is not reading from the new partitions (10-19). The log size is increasing for these partitions but the consumer offset is -1. How do I get the kafka connect to read from these partitions as well?

Comment: Consumer groups don't rebalance on new partitions. Have you tried issuing a /restart request to the connector? Or increasing its `max.tasks`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Kafka consumer is taking time to recognize new partition](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61925366/kafka-consumer-is-taking-time-to-recognize-new-partition)